# using AFNetworking's AFXMLRequestOperation with tbxml

Tags: ios, afnetworking, tbxml

How do i use the AFNetworking's AFXMLRequestOperation and parse the data using TBXML instead of the default NSXMLParser...looks like the alternate method XMLDocumentRequestOperationWithRequest will not work in iOS (as NSXMLDocument is not supported)

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement your own extension for TBXML, or decide not to use TBXML but KissXML that already has an extension:

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFKissXMLRequestOperation